# (Ruby) parsing a string with RegEx

Tags: ruby, regex

This is the string that I want to parse: `2 Sep 27 Sep 28 SOME TEXT HERE 35.00`

I want to parse it into a list so that the values look like:

```
list[0] = 'Sep 28'
list[1] = 'SOME TEXT HERE'
list[2] = '35.00'
```

The RegEx that I've been working on:

```
^\d{1}\s{1}[a-zA-Z]{3}\s{1}\d{2}\s{1}([a-zA-Z]{3}\s{1}\d{2})\s{1}([a-zA-Z0-9]*\s{1})+(\d+.\d+)
```

My values are:

```
list[0] = 'Sep 28'
list[1] = 'HERE'
list[2] = '35.00'
```

The `list[1]` value is off. I'm also probably not parsing the spaces right, but I couldn't find any guidance in the "Pickaxe" book or online.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is in your second capture group:

```
([a-zA-Z0-9]*\s{1})+
```

The parenthesized group is repeated, matching each of the words `'SOME'`, `'TEXT'`, and `'HERE'` individually, leaving your second capture group with only the final match, `'HERE'`.

You need to put the `+` *inside* the capturing parenthesized groups, and use non-capturing parentheses `(?:...)` to enclose your existing group. Non-capturing parentheses, which use `(?:` to start the group and `)` to end the group, are a way in a regular expression to group parts of your match together without *capturing* the group. You can use repetition operators (`+`, `*`, `{n}`, or `{n,m}`) on a non-capturing group and then capture the entire expression:

```
((?:[a-zA-Z0-9]*\s{1})+)
```

In total:

```
/^\d{1}\s{1}[a-zA-Z]{3}\s{1}\d{2}\s{1}([a-zA-Z]{3}\s{1}\d{2})\s{1}((?:[a-zA-Z0-9]*\s{1})+)(\d+.\d+)/
```

---

As a side note, this is a pretty clunky regex. You never really need to specify `{1}` in a regex as a single match is the default. Similarly, `\d\d` is one character *less* typing than `\d{2}`. Also, you probably just want `\w` instead of `[a-zA-Z0-9]`. Since you don't seem to care about case, you probably just want to use the `/i` option and simplify the letter character classes. Something like this is a more idiomatic regular expression:

```
/^\d [a-z]{3} \d\d ([a-z]{3} \d\d) ((?:\w* )+)(\d+.\d+)/i
```

Finally, though the Ruby documentation for regular expressions is a little thin, Ruby uses somewhat standard Perl-compatible regular expressions, and you can find more information about regular expressions generally at [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)

Comment: The code works perfectly, but can you please explain what this means? " and use non-capturing parentheses (?:...) to enclose your existing group:"

Answer (score 1):

You may have also been here and tried this tool, but I would highly recommend [Rubular](http://rubular.com). It offers very quick string parsing.

It looks like you already got the specific answer to your question, so I just wanted to drop this in for other people coming by so they can know where to go test their regex or just practice.

Comment: This would have been more appropriate as a comment, instead of an answer.

Comment: Indeed it would have, now that I think about it. Still learning the ropes of Stack Overflow.